# How to put server-side control in Literal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals

I want put a server-side control in a Literal. Is it possible? If yes, how? I know the description of the class says it all:

> Represents HTML elements, text, and any other strings in an ASP.NET
>   page that do not require processing on the server

Comment: That's not possible. By definition, a `Literal` control can only contain literal markup, not other server-side controls.

Comment: Sounds like you've "solved" half your problem. You may want to go back to step 0 and state why you think you want this functionality. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be wrapping server side code in other controls you probably want to be using Panel.  As the comments have already stated, it is impossible to treat literal text as a server side Control.

Answer (score 0):

Funny this comes up as I just looked through some of my old code yesterday.  Literals can do this.  I did this originally to emit user controls through a web service call from Javascript(yikes, I know...it was fun) but this will fit your needs as well.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litTest.Text = RenderUserControlAsString("WebUserControl1.ascx");
    }

    private string RenderUserControlAsString(string path)
    {
        Page page = new Page();
        UserControl control = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(path);

        //add the control to the page
        page.Controls.Add(control);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, true);

        //return the rendered markup of the page, which only has our single user control
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

Throw your literal on the page and assign it's text value to RenderUserControlAsString("Path to your User Control").  With that said, in your user control you must wrap child controls within a form control.

```
<form runat="server"> <asp:TextBox id="txtTest" Text="From User Control" runat="server"  /> </form>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: That's still not assigning server controls to a literal.  You're only ever assigning literal string text to the literal, you just happen to be utilizing server side controls to generate the literal text that goes in there.  ASP will still not treat the text inside of the literal as server side controls, which means they won't support event the way normal server side controls will, they won't persist changes to the view state, etc.  It's far easier to just use a panel.

Comment: Dude, I'm just answering the original question.  I'm not assuming what he's actually trying to do.

Comment: But my point is that you're not actually answering the original question.  You are not putting a server side code in a literal, you are only putting a literal control in the literal.  The fact that the literal was generated by a server side control rather than being hard coded doesn't change that.  The actual answer to the exact question asked by the user is in the first comment to the OP; it's not possible.  The only thing left to discuss after that is possible alternative solutions to the OPs actual problem.  Based on the OP's marked answer, that appears to be to use Panel.

Answer (score -4):

```
TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
YourLiteralID.Controls.Add(myTextBox);
```

Comment: This will bomb at runtime.  Literals don't support child controls.