# asp:TextBox is not working inside asp:Placeholder C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, sharepoint

I am trying to add some `TextBoxes` controls dynamically based on items in my database. This is my `asp:PlaceHolder` in `.aspx` page

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderHTML" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and now from C# code I am trying to create dynamic `HTML` and then that html render to `asp:PlaceHolder`.

This is my C# code:

```
 StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (SPListItem item in collitem)
 {
 data.Append(@"
      <tr>
          <th class='accordionSection esEmplCardSectionHeader'>
                <span id='lblSectionName'>
                    <asp:TextBox ID='TextBox" + item["ID"].ToString() + @"' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
          </th>             
      </tr>         
 }

 PlaceHolderHTML.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = data.ToString() });
```

but in browser the `TextBox` controls are not being shown. When I inpect element the textbox I am seeing the following result:
[image]

So the `textbox` inside html that is being sent to `asp:PlaceHolder`, browser is not knowing it as asp control and in  the browser nothing is being shown, so how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put server-side control in Literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101804/how-to-put-server-side-control-in-literal)

Comment: You can't just append ASPX server side markup and expect the engine to render it correctly. That's not the way it works. It's best to avoid dynamically adding controls if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the literal control is only for native html. Take a look at the rendered source. I believe you will see your server side markup in the source.

You will want to add the controls with new TextBox.

You may find it easier to forgo the asp Textbox all together and just use native that you manage the names and grab the values at postback.